# Where to find the "contours from points" model in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, vector, contour

I can't find the example model "contours from points" in QGIS 2.6.
Is there another tool for creating contours from points, besides the [QGIS Contour plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/)?

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for. What's the problem with the "contours from points" model?

Comment: Try removing the .qgis2 folder in your home directory. You should see the example model then.

Comment: Tried it, and still the Models in the Processing Toolbox says "0 geoalgorithm"

Comment: There should be a Contour script in the Processing toolbox if you are using the latest version. Try that. It seems like the model was removed, it's not in the source https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/models

Answer (score 1):

there is a contour-plugin, which you can load via plugin-manager. additional infos here: https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin

Comment: Thanks Kurt.
I'm familiar with this plugin, but the contours it creates are not as smooth as the ones created by the model.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the Contour Lines From Points model. I still have 2.4, I saved it for you as a .model

[Link to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw3vw4rwjhtrfzk/Contour_Lines_From_Points.model?dl=0)

Comment: +1, thanks for sharing the model. Seems a few people have this missing.

Comment: Thanks @HDunn
I copied the model from the 2.4 installtion I still have on my computer.

Comment: @H.Wiener Besimcha