# Models -> [Example Models] -> Contour lines from points: on MAC

Tags: qgis, contour, mac

I'm running QGIS2.6 on a Mac and can't seem to locate the "Contour Lines from Points" Example Model. SAGA is installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check if the model file is in your MAC. I use Windows so please forgive my ignorance when it comes to MAC but the file might be located in something like:

```
Macintosh HD / Users / YOU / .qgis2/ python / plugins / processing / modeler / models /
```

The model itself is called *contours.model*. If it does exist then you can use the **Add model from file** function in QGIS to import the model.

EDIT:

A similar post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123128/where-to-find-the-contours-from-points-model-in-qgis-2-6) mentioned the model missing. Fortunately, @HDunn kindly uploaded the file onto Dropbox. I have included his [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw3vw4rwjhtrfzk/Contour_Lines_From_Points.model?dl=0) which you can download the model file.

Hope this helps!